# Why Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, orm

My question here is why should i want use the entity framework instead of other XYZ.Can anyone please give a crystal clear idea/overview about this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you see this question:

[Entity Framework 4 vs NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639043/entity-framework-4-vs-nhibernate)

Answer (score 5):

There is no crystal clear reason.  Every solution requires a different set of tools.

All kind of factors are taken into account when choosing a persistence method:

1. Team skill set
2. Product size
3. Performance requirements
4. Data Structure
5. Cost
6. etc.

Comment: likelihood of being superceded by something else in less than 18 months... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's supported by Microsoft.